# SSIS Package Intermittently Failing

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2014

I have a really weird situation happening and would like advice on how to resolve it please.

I have SQL Server 2014. I have an SSIS set of packages that were migrated from SQL Server 2008, modified to point to the new server etc. One of these SSIS packages points to a view in a database also migrated from 2008. The packages are run every night to refresh some staged data. When run via Visual Studio, the packages take about 30 minutes in total to run and then that is giving me grief, takes about 10 minutes.

Every few nights one of them needs to be killed come morning via SQL Server Management Studio cause it has been running for over 8 hours.

The physical server then needs to be restarted that night to clear out the problem.

Yesterday I made some config changes based on the error log which said “The attempt to add a row to the Data Flow task buffer failed with error code 0xC0047020”.

When I googled this I got suggestions that the error was related to DefaultBufferMaxRows and the DefaultBufferSize. One of the suggestions is to increase these by a factor of 10 and see if that resolves the problem. So I did this.

I then Deployed and Rebuilt the Project in Visual Studio and tested the job via Management Studio. The run took two hours, so there were some alarm bells!

Last night the over night job (that starts at 2230) was still running this morning. I therefore killed the process in SQL Server Management Studio and then ran it directly from Visual Studio where it completed successfully (don’t know the exact timing).

I then tried to run it on its own as a job in Management Studio and had to kill it cos it was suspended and chewing up resources for users. It failed when querying a complex View in one of the source databases. I now cannot run it via Visual Studio and cannot even get a data preview in there of the view!

So into the source database and I Query the View directly. This returns data within a second for up to 13,617 records, but when I change it to "TOP 13,618", I need to kill it after 30 seconds.

I then Design the View and insert TOP 13,617 and boom, data is there in a flash. Make it 13,618 and data also is there in a flash. Make it 1,000,000 and I have the View completed within about two minutes.

So what gives? And how the hell do I try to track what is going on and fix it!

All thoughts are welcome!

Thanks for your help.

John

Comment: Given that SSIS takes a long time and TOP X in SSMS takes a long time.... I think your query just takes a long time - no big mystery there. So you need to optimise your query. How many rows does it return? The first thing I suggest is use CTRL-L to get the query plan.

Comment: Hi @Nick.McDermaid, thanks for your thoughts. I don't think that is the case because when I query the view with the Top 13,617 records it returns extremely quickly, compared to timing out with just one more record. And then if I Design the View (rather than querying it), the whole lot comes back quickly.

Comment: I suggest you compare query plans between the fast and slow versions in SSMS (TOP 13,617, TOP 13,618 and no TOP at all) using CTRL-L